What is TokenzQdBNbLqP5VEhdkAS6EPFLC1PHnBqCXEpPxuEb in process of creating spl token?
I trying make a token according to official document
I faced this part
https://solana.com/developers/guides/getstarted/how-to-create-a-token#creating-the-token-mint

What is address i marked here (TokenzQdBNbLqP5VEhdkAS6EPFLC1PHnBqCXEpPxuEb) should i change it ?

This is the Token extensions(or Token 22) program address, solscan address.
You need to specify it, if you are working with a token that will need token extensions features, for example, adding metadata using the metadata pointer or add a transfer fee ...e.t.c.
If you omit it, the CLI will fallback to using the original Token Program - TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA
For the guide you are using, omitting it will likely result in an error as it uses the metadata pointer.
Check out SPL Token Program guides here https://spl.solana.com/token
